# Anylogic: Dataset resource_unit_states_log

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have created a simple model (see first attachment) in Anylogic. Resource unit W1 is seized in service and resource unit W2 is seized in service 1. The delay time of service and service 1 is both 5 minutes. The interarrival time of source is 10 minutes and interarrival time of source 1 is 6 minutes.

Now I would like to analyse the usage state of both resource units, but in dataset resource_unit_states_log there is only the state "usage_busy" logged. Is there any possibility to also log the usage state "idle" in this dataset? Later in my evaluation I want to know the **exact date and time** when the resource was in state "idle". Currently I can only read the exact date and time for the state "busy" from the data set (see screenshot in first attachment). Theoretically, I could manually calculate the date and time of the "idle" state based on the existing values, but that would take a long time with thousands of dates.

[image]

Another attempt was to track the "idle" state using a timeplot. If I use W1.time() as x-axis value, I get the model time (e.g. 0, 1, 2 ...) in the dataset. But I want instead as in the dataset "resource_unit_states_log" the exact date like 27-12-2021 00:06:00.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve either of these problems?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AnyLogic internal tables/logs are not modifiable. They are as they are. If you want data in any other format, you need to do it by using your own data collection functions/codes. In your case, the second approach is pretty good. You are collecting information every minute and you can export it. I usually do the post-processing in Python. I work with millions of rows and it takes a few minutes; in your case thousands of rows should take some seconds. Here is how I would do it:

1. Export the data (in your second plot approach) into Excel. The data should look like this:
   [image]
2. Open Jupyter notebook (or any IDE).
3. Read the data into Python. Lets say you have saved your data as `data.xlsx`.
4. Input your `start_datetime`, i.e. starting date and time of your simulation.
5. Then just add the minutes from your data to the `start_datetime`.
6. Write the modified data in a new Excel file called `data_modified.xlsx`. It will look like this:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime as dt


df=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

#Input your start date and hour below:
start_datetime='2021-12-31 00:00:00'


df['datetime']=start_datetime
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df['datetime']=df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df['time_added'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['x'],'m')
df['datetime']=df['datetime']+df['time_added']
del df['time_added']

df.to_excel('data_modified.xlsx')
```

**Another approach:**
You can use the cells `On seize unit` and `On exit` inside the Service block and log the time when the resource is seized and released by using the function `time()` and write this information into a dataset. Then do the calculations.

You can also use some conversion functions of AnyLogic as below:

[image]